# Using Lua FFI with complex types

Tags: c, lua, ffi

Bit of a complicated use case... Trying to access a C++ Object inside of Lua FFI, via a C wrapper.

```
ffi.load("wrapper.so")
​
ffi.cdef[[
struct puppy;
typedef struct puppy puppy_t;
puppy_t *   puppy_bark     (const char *encoded);
]]
```

However every time I try to instantiate a puppy, it returns "size of C type is unknown or too large".

I've tried the following to get a puppy created...

```
pup = ffi.typeof("puppy_t")
pup.puppy_bark("some text")
```

Results in `struct puppy` has no member named `puppy_bark`

```
pup = ffi.new("struct puppy_t")
pup.puppy_bark("some text")
```

Returns `undeclared or implicit tag`

```
pup =  ffi.new("struct puppy puppy_t")
pup.puppy_bark("some stringish thing")
```

Returns `'<eof>' expected near puppy_t`

Assuming that the C Wrapper correctly has a Puppy Struct, Type, and the requisite method, how do create an instance of or a pointer to a Puppy in order to make it bark?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you instantiating a puppy?

Comment: Just added some examples

Answer (score 4):

You ask "how do I create an instance of or a pointer to a puppy in order to make it bark" - but it's not possible to create an instance of something without having its definition, and it's not possible to create a pointer to something without having an instance of it, and puppies don't bark with your code anyway (but there is a global function `puppy_bark` that creates a new puppy?).

It looks like you can create a puppy by calling `puppy_bark` (in which case, what a horribly badly named function!), but I can't be sure of that without seeing the actual code behind `puppy_bark`.

Since I don't have a specific answer to a specific question, here are some things that are likely to help you:

1. `ffi.new("puppy_t")` doesn't work because the FFI needs to have the *definition* of `struct puppy`, not just a forward declaration, for exactly the same reason this won't work in C++:

   ```
   struct puppy;
   puppy *p = new puppy;
   ```

   So, if you want to do this, you need to load the complete definition into the FFI. Note that LuaJIT's FFI *only supports C code*, not C++.
2. `ffi.new("struct puppy_t")` doesn't work because that's not a type that exists.
3. `ffi.new("struct puppy puppy_t")` don't work because that's not a valid type.
4. `pup = ffi.typeof("puppy_t")   pup.puppy_bark("some text")` doesn't work because `puppy_bark` isn't a member of `struct puppy` (as the error message tells you).

   It also seems like you're misunderstanding the purpose of `ffi.typeof`. According to the documentation, `ffi.typeof` returns a constructor for the given type, so that

   ```
   local new_puppy = ffi.typeof("puppy_t")
   local puppy = new_puppy(1, 2, 3, 4)
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   local puppy = ffi.new("puppy_t", 1, 2, 3, 4)
   ```

   If you want to call the global function `puppy_bark`, you can do that with `ffi.C.puppy_bark("some text")`.